# Batch file that can distinguish between VPN connection and LAN connection

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, vpn, lan

So basically I made a Batch file that backs up the local "*.pst" files to a network folder. What I have to do now is activate this batch file once a day, and only when the User activating it is connected via LAN, not VPN or WLAN.

Ive made a scheduled task to open the Batch daily, and only if connected to the right network. But it cant distinguish between VPN connection, WLAN and LAN connection...

Is there a way the Batch file itself "knows" the type of connection? Or is there a option with scheduled Tasks that can do this?

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN, the IPCONFIG command will have your VPN connection listed.

Comment: @squashman Thank you for the fast response!!
I didnt think it would be that simple...
But now Ive got another Problem.. This way i cant distinguish between LAN and WLAN, and I dont want to backup several GB of data over WLAN..

Comment: In Windows, by default, the LAN connection always takes precedence over the WLAN connection.  So if both are connected the computer is using the LAN.  If the LAN is disconnected then IPCONFIG shows Media Disconnected for the LAN connection.